# Magento SQL query: Get all simple products that are "not visible individually"

Tags: sql, magento, magento-1.7, entity-attribute-value

I am looking to write an SQL query directly on the Magento database that gets all Simple products that have the visibility attribute of "not visible individually", for which the value is 1 i believe.

Can anyone help with this? So far I have discovered that the visibility value is set in the table

> catalog_product_entity_int

but have been unable to progress further. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to use product collection for this

Comment: Why sql directly on the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many reasons to *not* do this without the ORM, all of which may (or may not) apply to your needs (store filters, reading data from the correct table, etc). At the very least, you can use the product collection object to build the query which you would run:

```
$coll = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$coll->addAttributeToFilter('visibility' , Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
echo $coll->getSelect();
```

The resulting query will look like this:

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) AS `visibility`
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility_default`
    ON (`at_visibility_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
    AND (`at_visibility_default`.`attribute_id` = '526')
    AND `at_visibility_default`.`store_id` = 0
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
    AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '526')
    AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 1)
WHERE (IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) = '1')
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this might work not tested.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE visibility=1";
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
foreach ($connection->fetchAll($sql) as $arraytest) {
    echo $arraytest['name'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately the table structure is a little more buried than that but I shall try and adapt the SQL. Thanks

Comment: therefore i suggest to use product collection rather than writing custom query . which is also bad practices in magento